# How to run Github android code if it don't have Apk file

Tags: android-studio, github

I just want to know how to run this code -
https://github.com/neelkadia/WhereAreYou

As it doesn't contain apk file. And when i download zip and open this unzipped file in android studio, the studio says "Nothing to show".
Please tell me how to run this application and make apk

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

1: open the unzipped file in android studio.

2: Build your file using build option from menu or from right side

[[image: 1]]

3: After building app us the run option and select your device to run app .

all done!!

hope this will help.

Comment: No, its not working.More over we can not open unzipped file in studio

Comment: what?? you can open the file using open file option easily. Are you getting any kind of error ? just try to open unzipped file which is showing like just only gradle file. after you just follow the steps as above my answer. Also try this video: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0MjorpDWxc)